# Помогите разобраться с RTSP

Tags: видео, rtsp, broadcasting

Я на Java запрограммировал RTSP сервер. Транслироваться будет видео без звука (просто картинки JPEG). Для этого я решил использовать формат MJPEG и конвертировал все картинки в один файл `media.mjpeg`. Воспроизводиться такое видео будет на компьютере при помощи проигрывателя Media Player Classic. Вот общение моего сервера с проигрывателем:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://127.0.0.1:1234 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: Lavf56.29.100

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY

DESCRIBE rtsp://127.0.0.1:1234 RTSP/1.0
Accept: application/sdp
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: Lavf56.29.100

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Content-Base: rtsp://127.0.0.1/jpeg/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 62

m=video 0 RTP/AVP 26
a=control:track1
a=framerate:25.000000


SETUP rtsp://127.0.0.1/jpeg/track1 RTSP/1.0
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=7326-7327
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: Lavf56.29.100

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast

PLAY rtsp://127.0.0.1/jpeg/ RTSP/1.0
Range: npt=0.000-
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: Lavf56.29.100

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://127.0.0.1/jpeg/;seq=0;rtptime=0

###
```

Где идут решётки ### начинается отправка файла `media.mjpeg`. Но проигрыватель не воспроизводит трансляцию видео, а через некоторое время выдаёт ошибку:

> Не удаётся воспроизвести файл

Что я делаю не так? В интернете находил, что видео как-то нужно кодировать в RTP-пакеты, так ли это? Буду очень благодарен если мне поможете, полгода назад помню пытался что-то сделать на RTSP, но ничего не выходило.

Comment: RTSP это лишь контейнер. Определелитесь с контейнером.... И лучше пользовать VLC, там есть режим отладки, больше инфы получите...

Comment: Ваши логи не похожи на Wireshark логи, а такие вещи лучше просматривать там, если уж хотите посмотреть обмен...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, думаете VLC заработает в отличие от MPC (Media Player Classic)?

Comment: Думаю, что если не заработает - минимум даст больше полезной информации в логах работы.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, попробовал с VLC: при получении первого же ответа на запрос OPTIONS просто ошибку выдаёт. VLC скорее всего к синтаксису сильно придирается. Вопрос основной другой: нужно кодировать фреймы видео MJPEG по RTP пакетам? Или просто бинарный файл достаточно отправить проигрывателю?