# Принцип передачи контента (видео) по протоколу RTSP

Tags: rtsp

**Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить принцип передачи контента (видео) по протоколу RTSP?** Дело в том, что в интернете очень мало статей про RTSP, и к тому же, 90% из них на английском языке. По сути, в статьях мало нужной информации, но мне всё же почти удалось создать самодельный RTSP-сервер. Попробую объяснить свою проблему.

Я создал сокет на TCP порте 1234. К нему подключается Media Player Classic (видео проигрыватель). Они общаются между собой и проигрыватель вскоре отправляет команду PLAY (в [моём втором вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775025/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-rtsp?noredirect=1#comment1212036_775025) описан диалог проигрывателя и моего сервера). **Правильно ли я делаю, что начинаю транслировать контент видео в *этом соединении?*** Зачем в таком случае мне проигрыватель в своём запросе SETUP указывает какой-то клиент-порт, *нафиг он нужен*, если мы и так на одном сокете сидим и всё в порядке (можно ж на этом же сокете трансляцию создать)? **Что означает `client-port`?** Я, если честно, уже начитался этих теорий про RTSP-протокол и уже сыт ими. На практике эта информация бесполезна.

---

Мне бы *особенно* хотелось получить ответы на мои основные вопросы, выделенные жирным шрифтом. *(а также мой второй вопрос, выше указана ссылка)*

Comment: Про RTSP есть один вполне конкретный канонический источник с точным техническим описанием: [спецификация протокола](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt). Непонятно, для чего статьи.

Comment: @D-side, я знаю эту статью. Несколько дней с ней копался, непонятно ничего вообще. Я пробовал в переводчике перевести - полный бред.

Comment: Это не какая-то там "статья по мотивам", это спецификация, определение. Да, там не самый простой язык. Не удивлюсь, если машинный переводчик ломается на нём.